# All images and containers disappeared after host kernel downgrade

Tags: docker

Good day.

On the host machine was installed kernel 3.16. After installation the kernel 3.14 via deb package I lost all docker images and containers. Output of commands "docker images" and "docker ps -a" is empty. Is this normal behavior of docker?

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am facing this while upgrading my host kernel from 3.16 to 3.18. FYI my host is ubuntu.

Answer (score 10):

I will answer myself. It may be useful someone.

Docker used storage driver "aufs" on the old kernel. Therefore the module "aufs.ko" must be loaded. In the new kernel support aufs was not be enabled and docker began to use storage driver "devicemapper".

Comment: Thank you for the research, I encountered a similar problem updating to v3.17.1 with the missing aufs kmod.  Were you able to install an aufs module to recover your containers and images?

Answer (score 3):

To actually fix it on Ubuntu, run

`sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

This will install the `aufs` kernel module that docker requires but can be lost during kernel upgrades. Not sure why the package manager misses this dependency.

Comment: Won't this fail again the next time the kernel is upgraded?

Answer (score 2):

As Denis Pitikov points out, images and containers can disappear if the storage driver that created them (e.g. `aufs`) is no longer available.

When run on Ubuntu 14.04, the current [Docker install script](https://get.docker.com/) automatically installs the `linux-image-extra-*` package (suitable for your current kernel version). This includes the `aufs` kernel module.

On some systems, the `linux-image-generic` package may not be installed. On these systems, the next time you run a `dist-upgrade`, the kernel will be upgraded but the corresponding `linux-image-extra-*` will not be installed. When you reboot you won't have the `aufs` module, and your containers and images may have disappeared.

To fix it: first, check that you're running a generic kernel already:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-49-generic
```

If so, consider installing `linux-image-generic`:

```
$ apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

That will upgrade your kernel to the version required by that package and will install the `-extra` package too.